# Send a message at a specific timestamp in Discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to discord js and trying to make my bot send a message at a specific time (set via timestamp).

```
client.on('ready', function(e) 
{
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)

let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('0 10 15 * * *', () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ID');
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID');

    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ebdc05')
    .setTitle('Another ten minutes')
    channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
});

scheduledMessage.start() 
});
```

I found this method that sends a message at 15:10:00. My problem is that I would need the bot to send the message every 31 hours.

I also found the method to write '0 0 */31 * * *' instead of '0 10 15 * * *'. And that works, every 31 hours a message would be sent, but I'm afraid my bot sometimes could send the message a bit after the 31-hour mark and just add up seconds and minutes after time, that at some point it sends the message at like 15:12:00 or sth.

So I came up with the idea to just make a timestamp, and add the time to always have the 31 hours, then let the bot send the message at the exact timestamp. Sadly, I found nothing to that problem.

Is that even possible?

---

Edit: The timestamp variant would be useful because I can subtract and add time to that very easily and also show it in an embed.

Comment: Are you certain that the timeout will drift in the first place? Maybe this isn't a problem?

Comment: No, I'm not, and maybe this won't be a problem at all. But if it happens, that's not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the `cron` library you're using is that you can explicitly tell it the minutes and seconds—in your case, 0.

It won't accumulate errors. Unless it's very broken, the `cron` library will do the "figure out the next timestamp" stuff for you.

The cron string `0 0 */31 * * *` means "Every 31 hours, when the time looks like XX:00:00". So it will never run at 15:12:00—or 15:10:00 for that matter. You've said "run at this exact minute and second", so it will.

Disclaimer: I tried to read the code of https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron to confirm this myself, but it's pretty convoluted. https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/tree/master/src was easier to read and it definitely is checking the timestamp every second.

Comment: Yes, okay. I also ran a test last night, sending the message every hour. Even tough I started at like 20:46 it send the next message at 21:00 (what is good).

Comment: The thing is, that with the exact time stamp I can add and substract time to that, and as far as I see I cannot interact directly with that crone string. Like give out the time when the next message will be sent.

Comment: @somerandomuser the library you're using looks like it has [APIs to get that sort of thing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#api), like `scheduledMessage.nextDates`

Comment: Yeah, just tested it, you can call `scheduledMessage.nextDate` inside the cron job to get the next trigger time

Comment: I think I somehow got it to work with `let nextdate = scheduledMessage.nextDates().toISOString();` thank you for your hint.